# Can a finite automata have more than one input states?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I was knowing that Finite Automata can have only one input states but several output states. Recently, I've come across an example of removing ^-moves that has many input states.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deterministic finite automata are equivalent to nondeterministic finite automata with epsilon/lambda transitions. Having multiple input/start/initial states is equivalent to having a single input/start/initial state with epsilon/lambda transitions to the desired input/start/initial states. It may not be "standard" or "usual" to speak of finite automata with multiple input/start/initial states but it adds no expressive or computational power.